# Sacred 1: What to do with the key from the wizard in the desert?

Tags: sacred

Near the Oasis of Ahil-Tar there is a wizard. He offers a game where the goal is to find a key in multiple vases. I found the key but I have no idea what the key can be used for.

Has anyone found out what the key opens? Has it any purpose at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 solutions :

- Keep it for glory of finding the key
- Sell it for gold

This key does not open anything (and I admit that a Key as a "reward" is kind of disturbing) so there is no use keeping it : [More information here](http://pctalk.info/Games/Sacred2/Wolfes.Lair/SacredUnderworld/Pages/Quest-OasisRiddleintheDesert.html)

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it is quite disturbing. They just could have places a statue, a ring or whatever as a reward... And thanks for the link, too!